# elixir: what are pros/cons of putting :inets:start in a function?

Tags: ssl, initialization, elixir, inets

Currently I have **:inets.start** and **:ssl.start** in the **hello/0** function. Is there documentation that discusses pros/cons of putting initialization code in that function vs. elsewhere?

```
$ cat lib/jsontest.ex
defmodule Jsontest do

  @u1 'https://example.com'
  IO.inspect @u1

  def get(u) do
    IO.puts((to_string Time.utc_now) <> " [get] " <> (to_string u))
    {_, { _, _, body}} = :httpc.request(:get, {u, []}, [], [])
    IO.puts(to_string body)
  end

  def hello do
    :inets.start
    :ssl.start
    get(@u1)
  end

end
```

Comment: Is it an application? Do you have a supervision tree? Is this a part of an OTP project? Is it under the umbrella? With the information given this question sounds like “should I have an ice-cream for the dessert or something else?”

Comment: It is a small application.  I do not have a supervision tree.  It is not part of an OPT project. It is not under the umbrella.

Comment: Then is really does not matter where to put those. Although it makes zero sense to use Elixir outside of OTP. I’d better go with an application, that starts those and has an interface to call `:httpc.request/4`.